# Calling already defined routes in other routes in Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, run-middleware

I am writing a web app in node.js using Express. I have defined a route as follows:

```
app.get("/firstService/:query", function(req,res){
    //trivial example
    var html = "<html><body></body></html>"; 
    res.end(html)
});
```

How do I reuse that route from within express?

```
app.get("/secondService/:query", function(req,res){
    var data = app.call("/firstService/"+query);
    //do something with the data
    res.end(data);
});
```

I couldn't find anything in the API documentation and would rather not use another library like "request" because that seems kludgey. I am trying to keep my app as modular as possible. Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Express Route internally from inside NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946943/calling-express-route-internally-from-inside-nodejs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you simply break this out into another function, put it in a shared spot and go from there?

```
var queryHandler = require('special_query_handler'); 
// contains a method called firstService(req, res);

app.get('/firstService/:query', queryHandler.firstService);

// second app
app.get('/secondService/:query', queryHandler.secondService);
```

Honestly, this whole business of nesting the call back inside of the `app.get(...)` is not really a great practice. You end up with a giant file containing all of the core code.

What you really want is a file filled with `app.get()` and `app.post()` statements with all of the callback handlers living in different, better organized files.

Comment: Thank you! I am just an Express beginner who is trying to get a handle on a project that is becoming unwieldy. Any suggestions for intermediate to advanced express tutorials/help sites?

Answer (score 26):

Similar to what Gates said, but I would keep the `function(req, res){}` in your routes file.  So I would do something like this instead:

routes.js

```
var myModule = require('myModule');

app.get("/firstService/:query", function(req,res){
    var html = myModule.firstService(req.params.query);
    res.end(html)
});

app.get("/secondService/:query", function(req,res){
    var data = myModule.secondService(req.params.query);
    res.end(data);
});
```

And then in your module have your logic split up like so:

myModule.js

```
var MyModule = function() {
    var firstService= function(queryParam) {
        var html = "<html><body></body></html>"; 
        return html;
    }

    var secondService= function(queryParam) {
        var data = firstService(queryParam);
        // do something with the data
        return data;
    }

    return {
        firstService: firstService
       ,secondService: secondService
    }
}();

module.exports = MyModule;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of middleware on your route, you can benefit from spreading:

```
const router = express.Router();

const myMiddleware = [
    authenticationMiddleware(),
    validityCheckMiddleware(),
    myActualRequestHandler
];

router.get( "/foo", ...myMiddleware );
router.get( "/v1/foo", ...myMiddleware );
```

Comment: Per http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html example: `app.get('/example/c', [cb0, cb1, cb2])`, looks you don't even need the spread operator.  Nice to know about, either way!

Comment: @ryanm Huh. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `run-middleware` module exactly for that

```
app.runMiddleware('/firstService/query',function(responseCode,body,headers){
     // Your code here
})
```

More info:

- Module page in [Github](https://github.com/AminaG/node-run-middleware) & [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-middleware);
- [Examples of use run-middleware module](https://github.com/AminaG/node-run-middleware/blob/master/example.js)

Disclosure: I am the maintainer & first developer of this module.

Comment: Can this be used with Router and if so how would I do that vs the examples shown? Thanks!

Comment: Morgan is showing wrong info of the route which is called by run-middleware. any help @aminadav

Answer (score 1):

I have used following way:
at userpage.js

```
router.createSitemap = function(req, res, callback) {  code here callback(value);  }
```

at product.js

```
var userPageRouter = require('userpages'); 
userPageRouter.createSitemap(req, res, function () {
                            //console.log('sitemap');
                        });
```

Also can use in same userpage.js router I can use for other routing as well. eg.

```
router.get('/sitemap', function (req, res, next) {
    router.createSitemap(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect('/sitemap.xml');
    }); });
```

Hope this will help.