# Redirecting get to post? res.redirect to POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here in the `GET` `/facebook` route i receive the authorization code from front-end after receiving that, i have to make a `POST` request to `/facebook/signin`

How can I redirect `GET` `/facebook` to `POST` `/facebook/signin`

```
router.get('/facebook', (req, res) => {
    // res.send(req.query.code);
    res.redirect('/facebook/sign'); // = GET /facebook/sign
});
```

`POST` route

```
router.post('/facebook/sign', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query.code);
    // i will do mine stuff....
});
```

Comment: It is perfectly possible but do you plan on adding a request body? If so, you should read this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling already defined routes in other routes in Express NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737371/calling-already-defined-routes-in-other-routes-in-express-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write 1 handler method and use it in both routes;

```
function doFacebookSignIn(req, res) {
   // Your code here.
}
```

or

```
// Must be defined before using it in code.
var doFacebookSignIn = function(req, res) {
  // Your code here.
}; 

router.get('/facebook', doFacebookSignIn);
router.post('/facebook/sign', doFacebookSignIn);
```

But as I pointed out in the comments, you should be aware that when using a request body in a GET request, [there are some things to consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect `GET` to `POST`, a redirect is used to notify an HTTP client that a resource has changed location and should attempt the **same** request using the new location.

It is noted in the RFC that in some cases `POST` will be downgraded to `GET` when the request is re-issued.

```
  Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
  receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents
  will erroneously change it into a GET request.
```

If a `POST` request is expected on the server, then the client should send a `POST` request rather than a `GET` request.